# Orchard CMS on Azure: Problems installing new modules

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I recently created an Orchard CMS instance on MS Azure. I wanted to add some modules but I am getting the error (within the module page):

> Error loading extensions from gallery source 'Orchard Gallery'. Unable
>   to connect to the remote server.

I'm not familiar enough with Azure to be able to diagnose what is going wrong. I've seen some pages that say that this is by design. If so, then I can just install modules manually. But if this has ever been changed and this is indeed an issue then, does anyone know a) what the issue is or b) how to go about diagnosing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of your Orchard CMS instance? (see bottom right in admin)

Check on the Gallery setting page (/Packaging/Gallery/Sources) that the url of the default feed is **https://gallery.orchardproject.net/api/FeedService**

Comment: I'm using v1.9.2.0. The default feed is "http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc". Once I switched it to "https://gallery.orchardproject.net/api/FeedService", it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: We should probably point out that installing modules in production is generally a bad idea: you should install modules on your dev box, and then deploy the results...